# I need to get the specific region of aws on the basis of country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

What I want is:-

If I enter any country I want the specific Amazon region(zone) for that country

say like if I choose Australia as country it need to give me 'ap-southeast-2'(Sydney) as

Amazon region for Australia.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is quite open ended, you haven't specified whether you need that in a drop down-list / auto-complete list in your ROR web app etc. Nevertheless what ever may the requirement this the data you need.

You may implement it as you require

```
+------+--------------------------------------+----------------+
| S.No |             Region Name              |     Region     |
+------+--------------------------------------+----------------+
|    1 | US East (Northern Virginia) Region   | us-east-1      |
|    2 | US West (Northern California) Region | us-west-1      |
|    3 | US West (Oregon) Region              | us-west-2      |
|    4 | EU (Ireland) Region                  | eu-west-1      |
|    5 | Asia Pacific (Singapore) Region      | ap-southeast-1 |
|    6 | Asia Pacific (Sydney) Region         | ap-southeast-2 |
|    7 | Asia Pacific (Tokyo) Region          | ap-northeast-1 |
|    8 | South America (Sao Paulo) Region     | sa-east-1      |
+------+--------------------------------------+----------------+
```